# Sharing contour plot attributes between subplots

Tags: plot, matplotlib

I'm plotting several contour plots side by side for visualizing the time evolution of certain function. I want each contour's value and color to be shared between all subplots, but each time I add a new subplot, the contour values are recomputed (as shown in the image below), so any comparison between them is meaningless.

[Contour plots with colorbars http://www.inf.utfsm.cl/~rbonvall/colorbar-and-contour-plots.png](http://www.inf.utfsm.cl/~rbonvall/colorbar-and-contour-plots.png)

I've tried setting manually different combinations of `cmap`, `colorbar` and `axes` attributes on each subplot instance, without success.  How can I share the contour plot attributes between all the subplots?  In other words, how to get the same colorbar for all subplots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly specify the contour values to be used in the contour plot.  Here's an example:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-1.2, 1.2, .025)
y = np.arange(-1.2, 1.2, .025)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.cos(X)*np.cos(Y)
Z = Z*Z

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)   # set levels automatically
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z-.1, CS.levels)  # set levels as previous levels
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, this is a sensible approach, but I'd rather have the values automatically computed, because I'll be plotting several different functions with different value ranges. If there are no further responses, I'll go with this solution and compute the values myself by finding the min and max values among all arrays.

Comment: Thanks! I had overlooked the `levels` attribute. Now it works :)